# list as command line argument in python

Tags: python, list, command-line-arguments

I want to give a list as command line argument in python. When i tried`

```
osize = sys.argv[1]

o_hres = osize[0]
o_vres = osize[1]

print osize

print o_vres
print o_hres`
```

output is

```
python temp.py 23,44

23,44

3

2
```

where expected was

```
python temp.py 23,44

23,44

44

23
```

please solve this problem

Comment: Please fix your question's formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is a string, so split it up:

```
osize = sys.argv[1].split(',')
```